# WPF Show Data in Grid

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a C# CLI program that scans for missing Windows updates and writes them to command line or serializes them to XML depending on the flag passed in. I'm trying to build a WPF component to this but am unsure of a few things. Specifically I'd like to write all missing updates to a grid in the center of my WPF main window. The appearance would be something like this (with gridlines between the fields):

```
NAME                                         SEVERITY      DETECTED
Security Update for Windows 7 (KB1234567)    Important     3/9/2014
Security Update for Windows 7 (KB7654321)    Critical      3/9/2014
```

My specific questions:

1. What type of control would I need to add to the window to house this data?
2. How do I send the data (detected missing update names and properties) to the grid for display?
3. How can I set the control so that it is collapsed (or invisible) when no missing updates are detected?
4. Will I need to add a scrollbar to the grid or will one display automatically?

Apologies for the simple questions. I'm really just looking for some examples to get started, and I haven't been able to find anything thus far that meets my needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What type of control would I need to add to the window to house this
>   data?

**[DataGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** control is what you are looking for.

---

> How do I send the data (detected missing update names and properties)
>   to the grid for display?

Bind `ItemsSource`of DataGrid to `ObservableCollection<T>` where T will be class containing data with properties `Name`, `Severity` and `Detected`.

---

> How can I set the control so that it is collapsed (or invisible) when
>   no missing updates are detected?

Add a `DataTrigger` to check if `ItemsSource` collection contains no data, collapse the visibility.

---

> Will I need to add a scrollbar to the grid or will one display
>   automatically?

DataGrid internally use `ScrollViewer`. No need to add explicitly.

---

Refer to the dataGrid samples [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30905/WPF-DataGrid-Practical-Examples) and [here](http://wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html).

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative `DataGrid` can offer [`ListView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control, it will be little "easier" than the `DataGrid`, he also supports the ability to sort columns.  For him also need to bind a `ItemsSource` collection to display:

> The `ListView` control provides the infrastructure to display a set of data items in different layouts or views. For example, a user may want to display data items in a table and also to sort its columns.

Example in [`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750972%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.).

Little add some notes to the wonderful answer of `@RohitVats`, all that has been said about `DataGrid` also applies to `ListView`:

> How can I set the control so that it is collapsed (or invisible) when no missing updates are detected?

In this situation, I advise you to adhere to the principle of [`MVVM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx). Use `Binding` and [`Commands`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921126.aspx) to create an independent application. You want to create property (for example `IsEnabled`) in Model / ViewModel and use bindings to set them in the `View`, in order to avoid apply directly to the Control. `WinForms` style app or "regular" applications creates a strong connection between logic and UI, which subsequently impedes further change and application maintenance.

Comment: Column sorting is available in DataGrid as well.

Comment: @RohitVats: I know, I did not say that the `DataGrid` does not support them.

Comment: I would generally prefer DataGrid. [DataGrid vs ListView](http://wpf.codeplex.com/discussions/40802).

Comment: @RohitVats: I usually too. I just introduced an alternative to the OP, he suddenly opts for `ListView`. Except DataGrid that there is another control that can come to him.